# What is Lord Rama's janma nama?

Tags: ramayana, rama

One of my friends said it starts with 'ha'. Could anyone kindly let me know the birthname of Lord Rama please?

Answer (score 4):

Lord Rama's birth name is Rama. There is no other name.

> "Elapsed are eleven days and the naming ceremony is performed, then
> Vashishta, the chief priest, **named the high-souled elder one as Rama,**
> Kaikeyi's son as Bharata, and one son of Sumitra as Lakshmana and the
> other as Shatrughna."

Sarga 18, Bala Kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.